# I cannot reference .Net Standard 2 library in .Net Core 2 project

Tags: .net-core, .net-standard

I have created a .Net Standard 2.0 class library and created some simple Dtos. Then I tried to reference it in .Net Core 2.0 web application and I could no do it. Visual Studio noticed that I should make a reference, but when I did that - nothing happened.

I'm using Visual Studio 15.5.1.

Comment: Many people can, so you need to describe more on why you cannot, like screen shots, content of your csproj.

Comment: @LexLi, I have reproduced this situation with freshly created projects. I put code here: https://github.com/mikuam/NetCoreReferencingNetStandard. The last commit, that supposed to add a reference, does not compile. I'm using Visual Studio Professional 15.5.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out, that adding using was not enough. I needed to update Resharper from version 2017.1.1 to 2017.3.1. It is actually version 2017.2.1 that added a support for .Net Core 2.0: jetbrains.com/resharper/whatsnew/#v2017-2.

Answer (score 3):

You missed a namespace import. Change `ValuesController.cs`

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
```

to

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using NetStandardLibrary;
```

Learn how to use Roslyn to fix such minor issues. That's an easier way out.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/getting-started-with-roslyn-analyzers

Comment: It turned out, that adding using was not enough. I needed to update Resharper from version 2017.1.1 to 2017.3.1. It is actually version 2017.2.1 that added a support for .Net Core 2.0: https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/whatsnew/#v2017-2.

Answer (score -1):

Try creating a .Net Core project with .Net Framework template.

[image: Add core project]